# What is the inverse of $y=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, inverse

I'm unsure if I've done the first steps correctly.

If so, how would you proceed after getting $10^x = y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$?

Comment: Have you started with the usual "switch $x$ and $y$, try to solve for $y$"?

Comment: I had assumed the log was base $e$, only because that would be the inverse of a fairly famous function, [hyperbolic sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Definitions). But yeah, if it is a base $10$ logarithm, that's a good start. It would be good to include a bit of your attempt in the question itself; it's liable to be closed for "lacking context" if you don't include anything besides the problem statement. But from your comment, it's clear that you've made good progress!

Comment: Subtract $y$ from both sides, then square both sides.  You should see what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the base $10$ logarithm is meant, and you have $10^x = y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$, that square root is the main source of difficulty.

The usual course of action is to get the square root by itself, and square, to get a nice equation that's polynomial in $y$:

\begin{align*}
10^x - y &= \sqrt{y^2 + 1}\\
(10^x)^2 - 2y10^x + y^2 &= y^2 + 1
\end{align*}

Now your $y^2$s can be cancelled from both sides, leaving the nice linear equation $10^{2x} - 2y10^x = 1$, and you shouldn't have too much trouble getting $y$ by itself, although it might look a bit funny.

---

Sidenote: If the logarithm were base $e$, this is the inverse of something called the [hyperbolic sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Definitions), $\sinh(x) = \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$. Yours should look similar, but with $10$ instead of $e$. You'll have to do a bit of cleanup to put it in the same format.

Comment: The denominator should just be $2 \cdot 10^x$, then that's perfect. Remember that unless you have $2^x \cdot 10^x$, it's not equal to $20^x$ (try $x = 0$, for example).